# embed dynamic image created from GD into email using PHP

Tags: php, email, embedded-resource

For starters, I am using the following:

- php 5.3
- PHPmailer - to send stmp email with google apps
- GD to create the iamge
- I am able to take a previously existing file, add text to that file and output to a browser.
- I am able to send email with an existing embedded image using simple functions within phpmailer
- I am **NOT** able to dynamically modify the first file, have it saved in memory, then embed THAT image in my email.

When creating my image, I am using a very basic sample script:

### EDIT

I modified my code to the following: seems to run faster as well as easier to read. An actual file is created however whereas I would prefer a temporary file I could destroy after or simply use binary data. Is there a binary output function similar to imagegif()?

```
$photo = imagecreatefromgif('sample.gif');
imagealphablending($photo, true);
$fontsize = 20;
$font = '../times.ttf';
$fontcolor = imagecolorallocate($photo, 0, 0, 0);
$angle = 0;
$x = 100;
$y = 100;
$text = 'THIS IS A BLOB OF TEXT YO!';
imagettftext($photo, $fontsize, $angle, $x, $y, $fontcolor, $font, $text);
imagegif($photo, 'test.gif');
```

unfortunately, this wants to output my file to the browser, then proceed with the remainder of the script and send the email (without embedded image).

I know I am probably missing something simple but has anybody run into this issue before?

Comment: You'd need to encode the image so it can be loaded from a data url, or write it out to a temporary file for the mail library to attach from.

Comment: IIRC PHPmailer can even create attachments from binary data. So a string variable might even do it already.

Comment: do you have any recommendations for functions deleting temporary files written to disk (test.gif in the example above)

Comment: I forgot to mention, I use unlink();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to a) save the image to temporary file using second argument of imagegif function; b) use PHP output buffering to capture the result sent to output and clean it from the response (see http://php.net/ob).

Afterwards you need to know how to embed the image as attachment to the email letter or copy it as real file with http address available and point the `<img href=""/>` to it.

Comment: I can embed a real (or temporary) image without any issue. I believe my challenge came in simply generating the temporary file itself. I was not aware the imagegif function could save a file in that manner. Good to know (though I wonder if simply generating binary data would be more efficient)